# It's 2021 July, what is a reliable mobile EOS wallet these days? Lynx seems to be dead

Tags: wallet, mobile, ios, android

I used to use Lynx mobile wallet on my android and iPhone, but they seem to not be working anymore. Whats a good mobile wallet?

Answer (score 2):

Greymass [anchor](https://greymass.com/en/anchor/) is preferred these days, but Android version is not provided. (Desktop and iOS only)

You can find its source code from:
https://github.com/greymass/anchor

Comment: why not android ?

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ I don't know. I'm not one of the Greymass team.
Greymass has a plan to release, but we don't know when it will be.